# Automatically replace space with %20 in URL

Tags: html, image, url, razor

I have some simple code:

```
@{ String path = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite2\img\content\1.png"; }
<img src="@path">
```

In Page Inspector it's working, images is displaying, but in web browser don't.

In PageInfo->Media I found this path and it looks like this:

```
c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual%20Studio%202012\WebSites\WebSite2\img\content\1.png
```

So, the problem is replacing spaces with %20 - browser can't find file from this path, but if I change %20 to spaces then image was finding.
My question is: how can I stop automatically replacing?

Comment: Please check out this question : [url-encode-string-for-href-asp-net-mvc-razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159382/url-encode-string-for-href-asp-net-mvc-razor).. that's part of URL Encoding just for your info.. ^^

Comment: @user3003216: it didn't help. I have still %20 in my url.

Answer (score 0):

```
@{ String path = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite2\img\content\1.png"; }

 HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(path);

<img src="@path">
```