# How to do URL encoding in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, urlencode, redirect, redirecttoaction

In MVC I am doing redirection of action method from one to another like this :

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { Id = Model.Id, Status = "success" });
```

And this redirection is working fine.But I want to encode this URL while show in browser.What I need to do for this ?

Comment: You want to change url sting in browser, right?

Comment: yes.And want to do it from controller.

Comment: make changes into your View then. The code you're showing above in your question is a redirection from Controller.

try this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159382/url-encode-string-for-href-asp-net-mvc-razor

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to URL encode parameters in ASP .NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901049/how-to-url-encode-parameters-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: can you provide more info about your problem? I think you pick wrong word, are you sure about **encoding** and not **change**?

Comment: I am just redirecting from one action method to another but I want that redirection URL should not show parameters and its values.That's why I wanted to do encoding.

Comment: What kind of encoding are you looking for? Base64? UTF-8? Do you perhaps mean encryption instead? _Why_ do you want to encrypt the URL, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Because i dont want to show my parameters value to user.Because he can modify it and can call the other thing.

And yes i want encryption in url.

Comment: You can apply any encryption you like on the string before assigning it. Are you sure you want this in the URL though? Can't you use any other serverside persistence mechanism, like the session?